# Pinning Multiple Files To Home Screen In Oreo

Tags: android, shortcut

My app which pins multiple files at once on the home screen used to work pretty fine till Nougat. But Google changed internals in Oreo so those old methods of pinning shortcuts don't work but a new ShortcutManager class has been introduced. Read [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html).

Now even if I try, I can't pin multiple shortcuts at once using this class. I apply a loop and calls the defined method to requestPinShortcuts but it only accepts only one shortcut and ignores others. So I wonder if I missed something in the documentation. Is there some way out?

Answer (score 0):

Document:[ShortcutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager.html#requestPinShortcut(android.content.pm.ShortcutInfo,%20android.content.IntentSender))

```
It's up to the launcher to decide how to handle previous pending requests when 
the same package calls this API multiple times in a row. One possible strategy 
is to ignore any previous requests.
```

If adding pin shortcuts in loop, launcher may only accept 1st or latest request. It depends on devices. So the question is going to how launcher recognize different request window. It is recognize by different foreground component.  If different foreground components sending request, launcher accept all requests. Even it is almost send in the same time.

Some launchers may not show dialog to ask if user agree adding shortcuts.  Some launcher show dialog. Even you sends multiple requests, user may not have enough time to agree all your requests.